# Nested If Statements in Excel /

Tags: excel, date, if-statement

Stackoverflow has been really helpful on my Nested IF confusions! I thought I'd ask one more question to help solve my seemingly *complete* lack of understanding the logic flow in Nested If's.

Current formula used in Cell (`P3`) is `=IF(ISBLANK(M3),TODAY()-L3,M3-L3)`
It works just fine, except for then there is no data in Start Date (`L3`) and Finish Date (`M3`). When both cells are Blank it shows the number `43,091`.
The logic that I need however is as follows. 
If both start date (`L3`) and Finish Date (`M3`) are BLANK, Result an Empty Cell (`P3`).
If Start Date (`L3`) has a date, and Finish Date (M3) is BLANK, Count the number of days between Start Date (`L3`) and TODAY.
If Start Date (`L3`) and Finish Date (`M3`) both have Dates, count the number of days between Start Date (`L3`) and Finish Date (`M3`).

I hate to be a pest but i just cannot wrap my head around it and have struggled with this for probably 2 hours now. ANY Help is appreciated everyone! Thank you so much.

James

Answer (score 2):

Add the test:

```
=IF(L3="","",IF(M3="",TODAY()-L3,M3-L3))
```